# Firebase realtime database recyclerview pass image to imageview in another activity

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have a recyclerview with an imageview that displays Firebase Realtime database images. When a user clicks the imageview, I want the image to open a second activity and display that image in another activity's imageview.

**Adapter**

```
class AbstractAdapter(private val mContext: Context, private val abstractList: List<Abstract>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<AbstractAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.abstract_image_view, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(mContext, PreviewActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("abstract", abstractList[position].toString())
        mContext.startActivity(intent)
    }

    Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(abstractList[position].abstract)
        .into(holder.imageView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return abstractList.size
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.abstractImageView)
    val download_btn: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.abstractDownloadBtn)

}
companion object {
    private const val Tag = "RecyclerView"
}
```

**Activity that shows the image, but it doesn't show anything**

```
class PreviewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview)

    val previewImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.preview_image)
    val bundle :Bundle? = intent.extras
    val preview = bundle!!.getString("abstract")
}
```

**Update**

```
class PreviewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var previewImage: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview)
    
    previewImage = findViewById(R.id.preview_image)

    Glide.with(this)
        .load("abstract")
        .into(previewImage)

}
```

I changed my code for the activity that receives the image, but nothing is showing in that activity.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Nothing happens. There are no errors shown in my code.  When I click the  image in the recyclerview, the image doesn't show up in that activity. That's my only problem

Comment: What does `abstractList[position].toString()` return?

Comment: It's supposed to return the string/data shown in the recyclerview.

Comment: It supposed. But what it actually returns?

Comment: It's not currently returning anything

Comment: What do you mean by "anything"? Is that line of code even triggered?

Comment: I seem to have confused you and I apologize. Let me explain my problem better from the start. The 'abstractList[position].toString()' code is the data that is being shown in the recyclerview. What I'm trying to do is pass that data to an imageview in another activity using intent, but I don't know how to receive that intent in the second activity.

Comment: If you try to log that value, does it print the correct value?